# Undeclared string in Arduino class

Tags: c++, class, arduino

I am trying to write a class for an Arduino library. I am having a hard time getting it to allow me to pass a string variable to a method within the class.

I keep getting:

> ...Calc.h:21: error: 'String' has not been declared

Referring to this line of code which is line 21 in Calc.h:

```
void printCalc(int a, int b, String s);
```

I don't understand why it says that it has not been declared, because there are no problems with my int's. and I didn't do anything different with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `#include` the header file that defines `String` before `calc.h`. `calc.h` *should* be the one to `#include` the header where `String` lives, but I see this mistake quite a bit with library developers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you `#include` the header where `String` is declared? Maybe this one:

```
#include <WString.h>
```